Problem with redirect lopp and css not loading after enabled ssl on cloudflare
The website's home page does not work (redirection loop) after setting https (cloudflare)

https://wolnekobiety.net/

All other sites work fine with SSL

https://wolnekobiety.net/o-nas/
https://wolnekobiety.net/sklep/tabletki-poronne-bez-recepty/

Apart from the home page, the problem also occurs on the store's basket page:

https://wolnekobiety.net/koszyk/

CSS sytles don't load here at all (they load everywhere else).
Why does a redirection loop appear on the home page when all others work?
Why don't   css styles load on the shopping cart page when they work everywhere else? What's   going on here?
I tried unplugging SSL, without cloudflare on http, everything works fine but I need to use CF with https.

Welcome! Please read why offsite links are not good. Without seeing some sort of settings, we aren't going to be able to help. Did you try replacing all http: to https: in your database? In the Network tab of the browser, it's showing that WP is doing the redirect. I would check if https: is set on the home/site url in the database.

In the database, all entries start with https://. However, on the page with the error (shopping cart), all entries in the page source that refer to css start with http (not https). I don't know why this page is different than on others and how to change these entries:

To start with https ??

This could be a cache issue. I would still run a search-replace on your database to change http: to https: and then clear all caches.
